# MethodError: objects of type Module are not callable

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am trying to duplicate a code in `Julia` using `Jupyter Notebook`.
and getting the error

> MethodError: objects of type Module are not callable

What am i missing here?

```
using JuMP, Clp
m=Model(solver=Clp())
@variable(m, 0 >= x >= 9)
@variable(m, 0 >= y >= 10)

@objective(m,Min,3x-y)

@constraint(m,const1, 6x+5y <=30)
@constraint(m,const2, 7x+12y <= 84)
@constraint(m,const3, 19x+14y <=266)

solve(m)
println("Optimal Solutions:")
println("x = ", getvalue(x))
println("y = ", getvalue(y))
```

Answer (score 7):

`Clp` is a module, you cannot **call** a module, ie. `Cpl()`, you want to call `ClpSolver` instead, see:

- http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#getting-solvers

Use: `m = Model(solver = ClpSolver())`